# Query data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I use SQL Server 2008 and I have a database with this table:

http://prntscr.com/8ei758

[image]

Can you help me query return data like this:

[image]
http://prntscr.com/8ei6v4

This is edit NOT from OP
Look like wants to group on Date, Source
And sum by day

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Please **explain** in plain English what you're trying to do - don't just dump two screenshots on us and let us **guess** what you want...... please read [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This looks like a super simple query. Why don't you try it and see where you get. Here is a hint....you want a case expression for each column (iOS, Android, WinPhone).

Comment: @SeanLange It also has grouping going on.

Comment: I think I get what you want but you need to describe in words beyond the data

Comment: @Frisbee those kinds of totals really should be done in the front end but can pretty easily be handled in sql too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't totally clear what you are trying to do here but I took a shot at it. I did not type in all of your sample data but this should show you how you can do this.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    ReportDate date
    , TotalAmount int
    , Source varchar(25)
    , Platform varchar(25)
)

insert #Something
select '2015-09-01', 120000, 'SmartLink', 'iOS' union all
select '2015-09-01', 204000, 'GooglePlay', 'WinPhone' union all
select '2015-09-01', 135000, 'Apple', 'iOS' union all 
select '2015-09-02', 50000, 'GooglePlay', 'Android' union all 
select '2015-09-02', 40000, 'Apple', 'iOS' union all 
select '2015-09-03', 30000, 'GooglePlay', 'Android' union all 
select '2015-09-03', 250000, 'GooglePlay', 'WinPhone'; 

with SubTotals as
(
    select ReportDate
        , case when GROUPING(Source) = 1 then 'Total' else Source end as Source
        , cast(SUM(case when Platform = 'iOS' then TotalAmount else 0 end) / 1000. as numeric(9,3)) as iOS
        , cast(SUM(case when Platform = 'Android' then TotalAmount else 0 end) / 1000. as numeric(9,3)) as Android
        , cast(SUM(case when Platform = 'WinPhone' then TotalAmount else 0 end) / 1000. as numeric(9,3)) as WinPhone
        , GROUPING(Source) as SortOrder
    from #Something
    group by ReportDate
        , Source
    WITH rollup
)

select ReportDate
    , Source
    , iOS
    , Android
    , WinPhone
    , iOS + Android + WinPhone as RowTotal
from SubTotals
where ReportDate is not null
order by ReportDate, SortOrder, Source desc
```

Comment: Thanks Sean Lange!  Great!

Comment: Most importantly, do you understand it?

Comment: Yes! I understand it! Thanks you!